# How can I save Generic List in to HttpCookie in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, cookies, shopping-cart

I write a shopping cart in mvc5 with session,but I want to replace implementation with cookies.Here is order action:

```
public ActionResult OrderNow(int id)
    {
        if(Session["cart"]==null)
        {
            List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item(de.Products.Find(id),1));
            Session["cart"] = cart;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            int index = isExisting(id);
            if (index == -1)
                cart.Add(new Item(de.Products.Find(id), 1));
            else
                cart[index].Quantity++;
            Session["cart"] = cart;
        }
        return View("Cart");
    }
```

and the Item class is:

```
 public class Item
 {
    private Product pr = new Product();

    public Product Pr
    {
        get { return pr; }
        set { pr = value; }
    }


    private int quantity;

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }
    public Item(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        this.pr = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

I replace if block with:

```
if(Request.Cookies["cart"]==null)
        {
            List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item(de.Products.Find(id),1));
            Request.Cookies["cart"] = cart;
        }
```

but I got two errors:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.HttpCookie'
and
Property or indexer 'System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

how can I do?
Thanks

Comment: `HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Cart"); cookie.Value = cart; Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well i dont think its duplicate since issue which user try to solve its a bit different and actually solving this by cookie is a bad way to do

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat, The dupe solves both exceptions in OP's question (and I agree its a bad idea)

Comment: I remember that my answer was devoted for bad suggestions even i answered question.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you can not save object to cookie, you must serialize it since cookie accept string.
The easiest way would be to Install Json.Net [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cart", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart)));
```

then to get cart you can use

```
var cart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(Request.Cookies["cart"])
```

**But the problem** with cookies is that they [are limited](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/)

My suggestion would be to store `Guid.NewGuid()` as a cart id in cookies and then store your cart in database with that id.